# Increment the value in third column by comparing the values in the 1st and 2nd Column in R

Tags: r

I have the data frame `mydata` with 2 columns `Col1` and `Col2`, I need to create a third column `Col3` which has the incremented values by comparing the `Col1` and `Col2` i.e if value in `col1` is >= 20 and  value in `col2` >= 15 then value in `col3` should be incremented by 1 and below rows should maintain the same values until it encounters the same condition.
`Dataframe` is as shown below

```
col1   col2      
 10     3  
 21     4  
 15     17  
 22     16  
 09     78
```

Resulting Data Frame should be

```
col1   col2  Col3
 10     3      0  
 21     4      0  
 15     17     0  
 22     16     1  
 09     96     1  
 07     78     1    
 23     17     2    
 24     10     2  
 24     20     3
```

This is my first project in R.

Comment: Plus use `dput` to supply sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` on the logical `vector`

```
mydata$col3 <- with(mydata, cumsum(col1 >=20 & col2 >=15))
mydata$col3
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(col1 = c(10L, 21L, 15L, 22L, 9L, 7L, 23L, 24L, 
24L), col2 = c(3L, 4L, 17L, 16L, 96L, 78L, 17L, 10L, 20L)), 
.Names = c("col1", 
"col2"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```